# What is keyboard shortcut to move split line between visual studio tab split mode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, split, keyboard-shortcuts

What is keyboard shortcut to move split line between visual studio tab split mode?

[image: Split image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to 'Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard', you'll find all commands you can bind shortcuts to. I think [there is no command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UaCw.png) that would fit your needs.